# GMaps Android API: Adding KmlLayer to Map Resets Marker Info Windows to Default

Tags: java, android, google-maps

When I add a KmlLayer to my GoogleMap (via #addLayerToMap), it resets all marker info windows to default. I am using a DefaultClusterRenderer to load my markers ("Waypoints"), along with a custom GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter that you see displayed in image 1.

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(googleMap, is, getApplicationContext());
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

These images show the same Marker before and after loading a KML layer into my Google Map interface.

[With no KML Layer loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8VR6.png) - Shows the proper custom info marker window.

[With KML Layer loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYWB8.png) - It resets the marker info window to default and completely ignores the custom one I had set.

Is there any fix for this?